# HTML DOM click() method not working in Internet Explorer 11 with Ext JS

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, extjs, click

I dynamically load a Ext JS multi-selector with data after its creation depending on another value. I found out that the only way to generate the Ext store for a multi-selector was to [generate a click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48654956/dynamically-change-the-search-options-in-ext-js-5-1-3-multiselector).

But it turns out that the click event doesn't trigger the search box to open in IE 11, leaving the store uninstantiated. Full [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2cpu) thanks to N. Jadhav, for some reason I cannot get the mods at Sencha to confirm my profile. The offending event, it kicks off fine, no error thrown, but the click doesn't open the search component.

```
     afterrender: function (form) {
                var plus = form.down('multiselector').tools[0];
                //Fire click event of plus button for creating search view

                //THIS DOESN'T WORK IN IE 11
                plus.el.dom.click();

               //Hide the multiselector-search
                form.down('multiselector-search').hide();
            }
```

Is there some other way to trigger the click in Internet Explorer 11?

I tried the below alternative with no luck

```
    var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
event.initMouseEvent("click",true,true,window,0,0,0,0,0,false,false,false,false,0,null);

plus.dispatchEvent(event)
```

Comment: You are closing the searchbox immidiately on this line: `form.down('multiselector-search').hide();`

Comment: @Tyr you could type down the solution (`window.setTimeout`) and post it as an answer... I can second that it works.

Comment: Ended up being able to get rid of the dynamic loading all together.  It was not an ideal workaround to begin with. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a div with the ‘onclick=function_call()’
 For example:

```
<div class=“button” onclick=“funcThatWillTriggerWhatIWant( a, b, some_object); otherOptionalFunction(var1, var2);” > stuff in here </div>

<script type=“text/javascript”>
    function funcThatWIllTriggerWhatIWant( a, b, obj){
        ...
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Not really, the click was to simulate a user click to generate the `MultiSelector`'s search store. I wanted to dynamically set the search options before the user actually interacted with the store, but it wasn't actually created until the user clicked on it. So I simulated a user quickly clicking and closing it to create the necessary assets.